# How to fix inferring latch(es) error when I use a for loop?

Tags: verilog

I'm implementing a module to count number of '1's in an input vector and cannot fix the inferring latches error.

Warning (10240): Verilog HDL Always Construct warning at top_module.v(15): inferring latch(es) for variable "count", which holds its previous value in one or more paths through the always construct File: /var/www/verilog/work/vlgaaQTZu_dir/top_module.v Line: 15
Warning (10240): Verilog HDL Always Construct warning at top_module.v(15): inferring latch(es) for variable "mask", which holds its previous value in one or more paths through the always construct File: /var/www/verilog/work/vlgaaQTZu_dir/top_module.v Line: 15

I've tried to add an else expression in the for loop after if statement, and also add an initial statement to initialize the value of count and mask.

```
module top_module( 
    input [254:0] in,
    output [7:0] out );

    wire [7:0]count;
    wire [254:0]mask;

    initial begin 
    count = 8'h0;
    mask = 255'h1;
    end 

    always @(*)
    begin
        for(int i = 0; i < 255; i = i + 1)
            begin
                if(in & mask)
                  begin
                    count = count + 1;
                    mask = mask << 1;
                  end
                else
                  begin
                    count = count;
                    mask = mask;
                  end
            end
      out = count;
    end

endmodule
```

I failed to pass the complying.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `initial` statement only initializes the variables once at time 0. You need to initialize every time you enter the always block so you never reference the previous values.

```
 always @(*)
    begin
        count = 8'h0;
        mask = 255'h1;
        for(int i = 0; i < 255; i = i + 1)
            begin
                if(in & mask)
                  begin
                    count = count + 1;
                    mask = mask << 1;
                  end
            end
      out = count;
    end
```

Comment: there is another error in the OP's code. Neither `mask` nor `count` can be declared as `wire` in this case. They should have been `reg`.